# Implementing a move constructor(rvalue reference) for an array class

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I have an array class I grabbed off of a website that gives an example of a move constructor. How would one implement this move constructor in an example program however? I feel like I understand the function definition, but I have no idea how one would make use of this in a program.

```
class ArrayWrapper
{
public:
    // default constructor produces a moderately sized array
    ArrayWrapper ()
        : _p_vals( new int[ 64 ] )
        , _size( 64 )
    {}

    ArrayWrapper (int n)
        : _p_vals( new int[ n ] )
        , _size( n )
    {}

    // move constructor, how does this come in handy?
    ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper&& other)
        : _p_vals( other._p_vals  )
        , _size( other._size )
    {
        other._p_vals = NULL;
    }

    // copy constructor
    ArrayWrapper (const ArrayWrapper& other)
        : _p_vals( new int[ other._size  ] )
        , _size( other._size )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < _size; ++i )
        {
            _p_vals[ i ] = other._p_vals[ i ];
        }
    }
    ~ArrayWrapper ()
    {
        delete [] _p_vals;
    }

private:
    int *_p_vals;
    int _size;
};
```

Comment: [What are move semantics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would one implement this move constructor in an example program however?

I think the code you have shows that already.

> I feel like I understand the function definition, but I have no idea how one would make use of this in a program.

Just use one of the several ways to trigger a move. For instance:

```
ArrayWrapper aw;
ArrayWrapper aw2 = std::move(aw);
```

Or even:

```
ArrayWrapper foo()
{
    ArrayWrapper aw;
    //...
    return aw;
}

// ...

ArrayWrapper aw2 = foo();
```

Notice, that in this last case the compiler is likely to elide the call to the move constructor anyway.

Comment: So does this make aw2 a deep copy of aw? by use of the move constructor?

Comment: @Need4Sleep: No, the move constructor is meant to *move* the content of the moved-from object into the object being constructed. That is the opposite of deep-copying

Comment: @Need4Sleep, It's a shallow copy. You can't use `aw` after this. It's good for temporaries that are about to be destroyed. It only copies a pointer, not the whole array.

Comment: ok, so this literally MOVES the contents of aw into aw2? Meaning aw is ready to be destructed/reassigned after the aw2 call?

Comment: @Need4Sleep: Redefined is not the right word, reassigned perhaps. But I feel like you got it

Comment: @Andy Prowl, yes yes, i'll edit to change my comment. Thanks for the explanation everyone.

Answer (score 1):

It is used in the same situations that the copy constructor would be but only if the expression being copied from is an rvalue. An rvalue typically refers to a temporary object. So, for example, if you have a function `foo` that returns an `ArrayWrapper` by value, the expression that calls that function would be an rvalue.

```
ArrayWrapper aw = foo();
```

Here, the `ArrayWrapper` object will be constructed from the temporary object returned by `foo`. The move constructor overload is chosen because the rvalue reference argument binds to the rvalue expression.

A move constructor typically leaves the object it is moving from in an valid but indeterminate state.